# Convert UTC time in UNIX time format to a readable DateTime format?

Tags: c#, datetime, unix, timestamp

How to convert UTC time in UNIX time format to a normal DateTime format (that I could read)?

Example of UTC Time in UNIX time format **1292985942**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double timestamp = 1292985942;
DateTime dateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp);
```

Comment: That'll do it :) The 4 0's are redundant.

Comment: And if it needs to be in local time, new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(1292985942).ToLocalTime()

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in perl like this
`my @temp_var = split(/ /,localtime(1292985942));`

Output would be

```
$temp_var[0] => Wed
$temp_var[1] => Dec
$temp_var[2] => 22
$temp_var[3] => 10:45:42
$temp_var[4] => 2010
```

Comment: You can do this in perl easily...Whats disgusting in this?

Comment: Because it's so complex compared to `$myString = localtime(1292985942)`.  Anyway the question is tagged C#.